# Angular @Input not updating UI when there is a change

Tags: angular

I have a child component that is receiving an Input. The value is being changed from the parent which I have checked in onChanges and it is being changed, but I do some decision making on the basis of that Input on the UI but it is not reflecting.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
{
  hasData(value: string): boolean {
    return value === 'hasData'
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: './child.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent{
@Input() hasData= false;
}
```

Design of parent:

```
<child
   [hasData]="hasData(data.id)"
>
</child>
```

Design of child:

```
<img *ngIf="hasData" src="data.png" alt="data" />
```

So far i have tried the ngOnChanges and the Input value is being updated correctly.

Comment: Please share the code of the parent, especially its cd-strategy as well as *how* you change the data that you then pass to the child.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com). With the code you posted, I don't see any reason why the input change shouldn't be reflected in your template/UI

Comment: This is still not a MRE, but you should avoid using functions as a binding to a `@Input` since they're called on every lifecycle.

Comment: Actually i had made sure that the updated value is being received in the child component.

Comment: See zhis [Stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yq1jbo?file=src/app/child/child.component.ts) for a working solution. If you still can't get it to work, please do provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think the root case is that you are updating your data.id somewhere without assigning new property to data. So you either create new object and assign it to data or call change detection after manual change

Answer (score -1):

As many others already have pointed out, the issue is that you have assigned the change detection strategy to `OnPush` on both components. The `OnPush` basically tells Angular that only check for updates either

- when the `@Input`-references changes as pointed out in the comments
- an event is occurred, such as a button click
- when change detection is triggered manually

In your case, you're passing a boolean (primitive value) that's passed by value, not reference, and thus no update will be triggered.

[Here's a Stackblitz to illustrate the issue.](https://angular-wqxgee.stackblitz.io)

To fix this, you have a few different options.

#### Use `markForCheck`

When the value is updated, mark the component to be included in the change detection cycle which will update the inputs.

#### Use the `async` pipe with observables

This is basically the built in version of `markForCheck`, since the code run when `async` is triggered marks the component for a change detection check with `markForCheck`. ([You can check out the source code here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cad7274ef90914f0c24d071473a6cbae0e5b8250/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L158))

On a sidenote as someone already pointed out, it's considered bad practice to use function calls in templates due to the heavy performance impact it can have. Consider replacing `[hasData]="hasData(data.id)"` with an async pipe instead and the use of some kind of an observable.